# Is an article (a, the) considered a part of the noun, when it comes to text formatting?

Tags: formatting

Let's say I want to bold the noun "emotion" in the text. Which is better way to do it?

1. **An emotion** is the feeling in the heart.
2. An **emotion** is the feeling in the heart.

So, should I consider articles (a, the) as parts of the nouns when it comes to text formatting?

Comment: This will most likely depend on the style guide you adhere to. My personal experience - and my personal practice - conforms to your #2.

Comment: Generally not. You just bold the noun.

Comment: Regardless of typographic choices, I think it's clunky to switch from indefinite to definite article *(**an** emotion is **the** feeling)* like this.

Comment: I also had a better feeling to format only the word and not an article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on if the article plays a semantic role in what you're emphasizing. Sometimes, you don't even emphasize the noun at all:

> You aren't *the* Keanu Reeves are you?
>   You can't eat only *one* apple can you?

If you mean to emphasize the noun, there is nothing saying that you have to also emphasize the article too. Only do so if it makes sense to do so. It also depends on *why* you are emphasizing something. Are you putting stress on its pronunciation—or are you using the emphasis to define the word as a word?

> The word *emotion* is . . .

But, perhaps:

> It's better to have *an emotion* than it is to have *no emotion*.

---

In short, emphasis signals your intent. (Note that I'm using italics rather than bold text, but the result is the same. Any number of stylistic devices could be used to emphasize the text.)

Barring any other context, my personal opinion is that the second sentence in the question looks better—at least it makes makes more sense to me that it's the noun, and only the noun, that's playing a particular role. However, if the sentence immediately followed another one—perhaps one that made the same kind of distinction as the last example of my own above, then, in that context, emphasizing both the article and noun could make sense.

So, don't consider the article to be part of the word. But do be aware of exactly which words make sense to emphasize—there's no reason why you *can't* emphasize more than one if that's the best way of representing what you're trying to express. However, it's certainly not a stylistic necessity.